# Why didn't humanity fight in oblivion?

Tags: oblivion

In reality in the war the Tet arrives and destroys the moon, causing earthquakes and tsunamis killing billions of people. 
The humans already knew of the existence of the Tet (odyssey mission), and they must have figured out that the Tet destroyed the moon, so then why did they not launch nukes to attack the Tet? Our arsenal is big enough to take out the Tet, isn't it?

And if they had launched nukes which failed, wouldn't nuclear fallout actually cause Radiation zones on earth (which were actually a hoax in the film)?

Comment: How do you know they didn't fight? Memory is hazy, but I recall that humanity did fight, but lost.

Comment: @SystemDown He's more after shooting some nukes at the Tet, which I'm not sure the humans even tried.

Comment: Your last question is a bit speculative and I'm not sure what answer you're awaiting to get from the movie for this (and in fact it might even be an answer to the previous question why they didn't nuke it).

Comment: "Our arsenal is big enough to take out the Tet, isn't it?" Who's arsenal? Real life human race or the movie version of the human race? There is a big difference.

Comment: Most movies are based heavily on symbology, therefore they seem to lack a certain amount of logic. For example in Matrix why should the machines depend on solar energy? Would it not be easier to build nuclear or fusion reactors? But this would hinder the progress of the story based on the mythology. So when you recognize a lack in logic, look for symbology first. If you do not find anything related to symbology or mythologic patterns, then it is simply a lack of logic.

Answer (score 6):

The TET's level of technology was clearly far superior to that possessed by Earth at the time of its attack. Even if a comprehensive plan of attack could have been mounted before the TET destroyed (and thus human civilization) there's simply no telling if that attack would have been successful. And after the Moon was destroyed, any human resistance would have been disorganized and more geared to combating the "Jack" clones sent to Earth, rather than attacking the vessel which sent them.

Basically, the TET's arrival was probably not seen as being a threat until it was too late to organize a coordinated defense against it.

Comment: but the real jack and victoria were taken inside the Tet when it was near Titan.. so would that not have given enough time to humanity seeing as two humans were captured by an alien entity on its way to earth??

Comment: The assumption may have been that they were killed and not seized by the TET. Even if that were the case, it's clear from real life that getting humanity to cooperate on common goals is often very difficult, bordering upon the impossible.